# Custom password bitlocker via command prompt or powershell C#

Tags: c#, powershell, bitlocker

I'm stuck on a problem with BitLocker.

Essentially, I'm trying to develop a tool in C# that automatically encrypts external drives with a customized password and saves the recovery key (file) into a directory chosen by me.

I found some commands to be executed via `cmd`, but unfortunately I'm only able to save the recovery key file *without* using a customized password.

Just to be more clear this is what I mean. I'd like to set a custom password as I'm writing here:

[image: Set Custom Password]

After I'd like to save the recovery file into a custom directory:

[image: Save Recovery File into Custom Directory]

Is that possible? After reading a lot of references on Microsoft, I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI in C# or PowerShell to configure Bitlocker. There are also a bunch of Bitlocker cmdlets available in Windows 8.1 and above. You might want to look at [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/05/26/powershell-and-bitlocker-part-2/) for a deep dive on PowerShell and Bitlocker.